# Prerender for reactjs app containjng react-router

Tags: reactjs, prerender

I have made my first single page app, which routes using react router, makes form submissions using axios, is responsive to screen sizes. And all works how I want it too.

I have had it hosted using AWS. However I now realise that my SEO is poor or basically non existent. So now I’m looking into prerender io.

After doing some research I have doing a lot of people saying it does not work with react-router for some reason I don’t really understand.

I’m asking what is the best way for me to achieve the best SEO results. Keeping in mind I don’t have a back end.

And if I use prerender io, what is the best way for me to overcome the issues caused by react router ?

Do I need to get rid of react router and make all my links  Tags with href instead ?

Answer (score 0):

Prerender.io renders pages in a Chrome browser so we won't have any problems rendering websites that use react-router. We will be able to render any website that Chrome can render.

Please let us know if you run into any issues! We're always happy to help. support@prerender.io